# pg_basebackup: directory "/u01/edb/as9.6/data/edbdata/syno/DATA/ascii_data" exists but is not empty

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I run the following command:

```
pg_basebackup -vP -D /dataBackups/odp-manual-db-backup  |tee -a
```

Following output:

```
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: directory "/u01/edb/as9.6/data/edbdata/syno/DATA/ascii_data" exists but is not empty
I also tried to run the backup in different way:-
[postgres@odpdb1test ~]$ sh /u01/integration_scripts/backup_scripts/BART_BACKUP.sh
WARNING: no obsolete backup(s) exist for server 'epas'
ERROR: backup failed for server 'epas'
unable to open file (/dataBackups/odpdb_BART/Backup/epas/1688293480760/base/pg_tblspc/17709/PG_9.6_201608131/17679/19735), Input/output error
WARNING: no obsolete backup(s) exist for server 'epas'
```

after failed the script, I run the bart-show backup command to see the backup status and the first backup is showing for `01-June-2023` and the wal size is `69.44 GB`

```
[postgres@odpdb1test ~]$ bart show-backups
 SERVER NAME   BACKUP ID       BACKUP NAME   BACKUP PARENT   BACKUP TIME               BACKUP SIZE   WAL(s) SIZE   WAL FILES   STATUS
 epas   1663704006404 none none  2023-06-01 15:41:17 +04   407.93 MB     69.44 GB      4444        active
 epas   1663617606182 none none  2023-06-01 15:39:44 +04   407.93 MB     48.00 MB      3           active
 epas   1663531210123 none none  2023-06-01 15:38:10 +04   407.93 MB     48.00 MB      3           active
```

How to fix this issue?